# PhantomJS PDF output is smaller than expected

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have following PhantomJS script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {
    width: screen.width,
    height: screen.height
};

console.log(screen.width);

page.paperSize = {
    width: screen.width,
    height: screen.height
};

page.open('https://www.google.co.id/', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('export.pdf');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
});
```

I was expecting the PDF output to have same size as my screen, but when I zoom it to 100%, it turns out that the size is smaller.
[image]

Is there something I missed? or is this a bug?
I'm using Windows version 1.9.7 from download page.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you didn't zoom enough. Just because your PDF reader shows 100% doesn't mean it's 100%.

Comment: @artjom thanks for the reply, but I'm pretty sure the PDF reader is correctly showing 100%. This is because I also tested with `page.paperSize = {format: 'Letter'}`, and it really shows correct size when zoomed 100%